# Unable to extract date value from website with Python and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im tying to extract date from one website. I want date/time when news article is published.
This is my code:

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

```
url = "http://buchholterberg.ch/de/Gemeinde/Information/News/Newsmeldung?filterCategory=22&newsid=911"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')


date_tag = 'div#middle p' # this gives me all the paragraphs
date = soup.select(date_tag)
print(date)
```

You can also try with this website:

```
url = 'http://www.embrach.ch/de/aktuell/aktuellesinformationen/?action=showinfo&info_id=1098080'
```

Please check out the `url`, thats the website that I want to scrape, and date/time that I want to get is: `13:05:28 26.11.2020`

This is my css selector that only gives me paragraphs, but date/time is not in paragraph, its in font tag.

```
date_tag = 'div#middle p'
```

But when i set my css selector to:

```
date_tag = 'div#middle font'
```

I get []

Is it possible to extract data thats not in any child tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you grab those elements, you'll notice that date is the next sibling node to the `<h1>` tag. So get the `<div id="middle">` tag. Then within that tag, get the `<h1>` tag. then from that `<h1>` tag, get the `.nextSibling` (there's also `.previousSibling` if it's placed before a certain tag element) which is the text. Then it's just a matter of some string manipulation.

**Code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://buchholterberg.ch/de/Gemeinde/Information/News/Newsmeldung?filterCategory=22&newsid=911"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

date = soup.find_all('div',{'id':'middle'})
print(date)

for each in date:
    print(each.find('h1').nextSibling.split(':',1)[-1].strip())
```

**Output:**

```
13:05:28 26.11.2020
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this (or something like this) only with css selector? So that I can onlu change date_tag ?

Comment: y. just change `date = soup.find_all('div',{'id':'middle'})` to `date = soup.select('div#middle')`

Answer (score -1):

You would have to extract the entire text as well, since that is all the same element. But what you can do is to take the  element, since it is basically the same, except a few minutes which i assume it doesnt matter too much. If you need help with choosing the h1 element let me know

Comment: I know how to extract specific element, but I do not know how to extract data thats not in any child element. Sometimes date/time is on the top, then it goes h1 and p's, and sometimes its on the bottom, and sometimes in the middle. Check out the other website

Comment: @taga well you cant do the same for different sites with different html codes, what you can do is to scrape the p tag, since the date is within the "p" tag, i doubt you can specify something that is not specified. in the first example you can take the h1 to only get the date tho

Comment: I know that I cant do that with the same code, i'm just giving the example. In first case, date is not in h1 tag (i want this date 26.11.2020). In second case date is not in p tag

Comment: oh yes sorry, it isnt within the h1 tag, but you then have to probably take the next parent(the div of both sites), or you might take the findSibling function, not exactly sure what it does

Comment: why do you downvote the answer? its right what i said